# How can we pass string[] values to lambda call using .net core

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Here in the below `externalRateCardIds` is a `string[]`. I need to pass the `string[]` to invoke lambda but when trying to call the endpoint, it tells that no input has been sent. How can we pass `string[]` to lambda call using `JObject`?

```
JArray array = new JArray();
array.Add(externalRateCardIds);

JObject queryParam = new JObject();
queryParam.Add("externalRateCardIds", array);

var externalRateCardLambdaResponse = 
await _lambdaInvoker.InvokeLambdaWithResponseAsync(
    EnvironmentVariables.ApiLambdaLongName,
    $"/api/Bill/GetBillByExternalID",
    "get", 
    new JObject(), 
    queryParam);
```

Comment: In the future, please specify which JSON parser you are using - Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json - in the post's tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[`JArray.Add`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Add.htm) adds an *item* to the array, not a range of items (similar to the difference between `List<T>.Add` and `List<T>.AddRange`). If you intend to populate your JArray with the values from your string array (one token per string), a simple loop would suffice.

```c#
JArray array = new JArray();
foreach (var id in externalRateCardIds)
    array.Add(id);
//...
```

Comment: Thanks. So adding each data from string[] to JArray using foreach loop and creating JObject to pass those values to lambda call will be the right approach?

Comment: Trace or log the final json result to verify. My answer will correctly populate the JArray with the string array's items. Ensuring the resulting query string conforms to the API is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Did this fix the issue you were having generating a valid json string for the lambda call @karthikeyansivakumar?